# Having trouble updating environment with PUT request in postman

Tags: postman, put

I am sure this is very simple, and I am relatively new to Postman so please forgive me, but I am having trouble updating my environment with a PUT request in postman.

Here is my pre-request script:

```js
var new_env = JSON.parse(environment.cloned_environment);
new_env.done_artists = environment.done_artists;
new_env.artists = environment.artists;
(delete new_env.cloned_environment);
var values = [];

_.each(new_env, function (value, key) {
    values.push({"key": key, "value": value});
});
console.log(values);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("updated_environment", JSON.stringify(values));
```

And here is the error that I keep receiving when I try running my collection:

[image: error]

I believe that there are a couple of things that I am doing wrong. I have referenced the Postman Pro API documentation and understand that the PUT request for an environment requires you to pass x-api-key with your generated key, which I have, and set as an environment variable so that I could reference it in the header, but beyond that I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is a screenshot of my environment variables for reference as I think it might have something to do with that:

[image: variables1]

[image: variables2]

[image: variables3]

Comment: Could you please add request body to the question?

Comment: What's the output of values? Is that what you're using in the request body? Have you tested the PUT request with some hardcoded values to ensure that it contains the correct structure for the Postman API?

Comment: @Div the output of the body is the following: `{
    "environment": {
        "values": {{updated_environment}}
    }
}`

Comment: @DannyDainton I have not tried that because at this point because I am working through a postman tutorial on how to play with Spotify's API. I am lost because I am not sure what value I should be assigning to the parameter 'environment_id'. Here is an example of my PUT request: 'https://api.getpostman.com/environments/{{environment_id}}'